# using Bootstrap Accordion with Wordpress ACF repeater fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, bootstrap-accordion

I am using Bootstrap Accordion with ACF and have a repeater in a repeater section.  I get all the data and it is displayed as it should be but when I click on the title to open the body the class changes to "collapse show" and the accordion opens for a fraction of a second only to close again immediately.  Does any one have any ideas? Here's the code:

```
<div id="accordion">
                <div class="card">
                <?php 
                if( have_rows('instructions_android')):
                    $i = 1;

                    while ( have_rows('instructions_android')) : the_row();

                ?>
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>">
                            <span class="instr-title"><?php echo get_sub_field('etape_installation_no'); ?> : </span><span class="instr-title"><?php echo get_sub_field('titre_du_step'); ?></span>
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $i; ?>" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <?php
                $i++;?>
                    <div class="card-body">
                            <ul>
                                    <?php 
                                    $j = 1;
                                    if( have_rows('descr_step')):

                                        while ( have_rows('descr_step')) : the_row();
                                        ?>
                                        <li><?php echo get_sub_field('description'); ?></li>
                                    <?php 
                                            $j++;
                                        endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>      
                        </div><!--card body-->
                    </div>
                </div><!--card-->

           <?php endwhile;
            endif;?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="accordion-list">
          <ul>
            <?php
            $faq_section = get_field('faq_section');
            foreach($faq_section['question_and_answer'] as $key => $qas){ ?>
              <li>
                    <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="collapse" data-bs-target="#accordion-list-1<?php echo $key; ?>"> <?php echo $qas['question']; ?> <i class="bx bx-chevron-down icon-show"></i><i class="bx bx-chevron-up icon-close"></i></a>
                    
                    <div id="accordion-list-1<?php echo $key; ?>" class="collapse <?php if($key == 0 ){ echo "show"; } ?>" data-bs-parent=".accordion-list">
                      <p> <?php echo $qas['answer']; ?> </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
            <?php
            }
              ?>

            <!-- <li>
              <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#accordion-list-2" class="collapsed"><span>02</span> Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc? <i class="bx bx-chevron-down icon-show"></i><i class="bx bx-chevron-up icon-close"></i></a>
              <div id="accordion-list-2" class="collapse" data-bs-parent=".accordion-list">
                <p>
                  Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. Id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.
                </p>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#accordion-list-3" class="collapsed"><span>03</span> Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit? <i class="bx bx-chevron-down icon-show"></i><i class="bx bx-chevron-up icon-close"></i></a>
              <div id="accordion-list-3" class="collapse" data-bs-parent=".accordion-list">
                <p>
                  Eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci. Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis
                </p>
              </div>
            </li> -->

          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).